# Simple protyping vs planned design in object oriented programming using python

Tags: python, oop

I am beginer in object oriented programming. Below are protype & planned design code to add sum of time duration, simple prototype works for me but not getting output using using planned design (need help in 2nd part after  last line of code to  display output), please help, thanks a lot

Simple protype code:it works

```
class time:
    '''save time'''
t1=time()
t1.sec=108
t1.min=52
t1.hour=12
print("t1=(%g:%g:%g)"%(t1.hour,t1.min,t1.sec))
t2=time()
t2.sec=100
t2.min=56
t2.hour=7
print("t2=(%g:%g:%g)"%(t2.hour,t2.min,t2.sec))
def add_time(t1,t2):
    sum=time()
    sum.sec=t1.sec+t2.sec
    sum.min=t1.min+t2.min
    sum.hour=t1.hour+t2.hour
    if sum.sec>=60:
        sum.sec-=60
        sum.min+=1
    if sum.min>=60:
        sum.min-=60
        sum.hour+=1
    return sum
def print_result(sum):
    print("sum of t1 & t2 is(%g,%g,%g)"%(sum.hour,sum.min,sum.sec))
a=add_time(t1,t2)
print_result(a)
```

Planned design:need help after last line of code to display output.

```
class time:
    '''save time'''
t1=time()
t1.sec=108
t1.min=52
t1.hour=12
print("t1=(%g:%g:%g)"%(t1.hour,t1.min,t1.sec))
t2=time()
t2.sec=100
t2.min=56
t2.hour=7
print("t2=(%g:%g:%g)"%(t2.hour,t2.min,t2.sec))
def time_to_int(time):  
   minutes=time.hour*60+time.min

   seconds=minutes*60+time.sec
   return seconds
def int_to_time(seconds):
Time=time()

    minutes,Time.sec=divmod(seconds,60)

    time.hour,Time.minute=divmod(minutes,60)
    return Time
def add_time(t1,t2):

    seconds=time_to_int(t1)+time_to_int(t2)
    return int_to_time(seconds)
```

Comment: How do we know it doesn’t work?

Comment: @peter wood sir, actually in second code everything is correct, I think, but I am not to display output for this by using print, means I am not able to manipulate it. Please help me. Thanks a lot